# Why does this sentence use the perfect past tense?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

I am an esl student. I have read a paragraph from the book *The Old Man and Sea* and found some tense problems. I don't know if I change the tense to this sentence, will it make sense?

from this

> “I’ve been asking you to,“ the boy told him gently. “I have not wished to open the container until you were ready.“

to this

> "I not wished to open the container until you were ready."

And what is the different between 'I only needed time to wash' and 'I only need time to wash'?　why the word 'need' need to be in past tense.

> “I’m ready now,“ the old man said. “I only needed time to wash.“

Comment: You haven't just changed the tense: you have missed out *not*. Was that deliberate?

Comment: You have not changed the tense. It's still past tense. You've taken out the auxiliary _have_ of the perfect construction, and the negative _not_ that allows _until you are ready_ to be grammatical in a perfect construction. The negation is **much** more important than the "tense"; _only_ is also a negative, and the difference you ask about is simply present versus past for the washing.

Comment: @John Lawler, thank you for the quick response. So Do you mean If I don't need the negation, I can use simple past tense?

Comment: No. I mean that the sentence you modified is ungrammatical because you removed the _not_. The phrase _until you were ready_ requires a length of time to end with _until_, but _open_ does not take a length of time but a point in time. Not opening, on the other hand, does indicate a length of time in which it is closed, so it licenses the use of _until_. As I said, negation is much more important than "tense". If your teacher goes on and on about "tenses", and never mentions negation, you're in trouble.

Comment: "have not wished" is _present_ perfect, not past. Past perfect would be *"had not wished"*

Comment: @Spencer: Quite correct. Thank you. I phrased it wrong, but as I said, the negation is far more important than the tense, and even more important then the name of the tense.

Comment: @John I was criticizing the title rather than your comment.

Comment: Can someone with the power to do so migrate this to ELL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence, "I have not wished to", is in the [present perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html) tense.  We use that tense to relate an action or a state in the past to the present.  The boy is saying that up until this point, he did not wish to open the container.  You can't say "I not wished", because that's not correct; when you negate a verb in English, you have to use *do*, like *I wish/I do not wish*.  In the past tense, you conjugate *do*, but not the verb you're negating, which remains in its bare infinitive, like *I wished/I did not wish*.  So the sentence would have to be "I did not wish to open the container..."

For "I only needed time to wash" vs. "I only need time to wash", it's in the past tense because the needing is in the past.  The old man does not need to wash *now*, he needed to wash *earlier*, but he is ready now.